# Как преобразовать ArrayList с объектами в строку

Tags: java, android

Необходимо `ArrayList`, в котором находятся экземпляры класса взять и перевести все его содержимое в строку. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: переопределите у класса метод toString, а потом просто вызывайте его у нужных экземпляров класса. если нужна вся коллекция, то делайте это в цикле.

Answer (score 3):

Переопределить метод `toString()` у класса, как вам нужно, и вызвать `toString()` у `ArrayList`'a.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list = objectList.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(toList());
```

С синтаксисом мог ошибиться.

Comment: в андроид стримы доступны с api24, что фактически равно их отсутствию, так как никто не разрабатывает пока только под последнее актуальное api (android 7), таких устройств, условно, еденицы.